# How to read a xml request from server into a dictionary key value

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I am looking to read the following into a key value dictionary for a web service.

```
Dictionary<string, string> att = new Dictionary<string, string>();


<Req>
<ID>myProg</ID>
<FID>myID</FID>

<att attName="fName"><Value></Value></att>
<att attName="lName"><Value>Doe</Value></att>
<att attName="Add"><Value>222 Fork Drive</Value></att>
</Req>
```

I know I can do foreach for the the part where there is actually a attName and value, how can I do that for the first two parts?

Someone said what I have done so far:

```
void Main()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
    doc.Load("myxmldoc.xml");
    var re = doc;            
    foreach (System.Xml.XmlElement  r in re)
    {
               Console.WriteLine(r);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything ? This is not a please code this for me site. It all depends exactly how you want the data to be stored in the dictionary.

Comment: well I don't know what you mean by "please code this for me site".. but this is what I have tried, I created an xml document and read it in, in a foreach looping through System.Xml.XmlElement.

Comment: If you have read it in then you should post the code. And by please code this for me site means that you are asking us to code for you. This is a helping site to help fix broken code.

Comment: That is fine you don't have to help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you going to post the code ?

Comment: so far .. that is my code.. I haven't found a way to add it to the dictionary anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
var root = XElement.Parse(xml);
var att = root.Nodes().Where(n => n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    .Select(node =>
    {
        var element = (XElement)node;
        return element.Name.LocalName.Equals("att")
            ? Tuple.Create(element.Attribute("attName").Value, ((XElement)element.FirstNode).Value)
            : Tuple.Create(element.Name.LocalName, element.Value);
    })
    .ToDictionary(tuple => tuple.Item1, tuple => tuple.Item2);
```

Comment: this is part of the answer ... I need to add the nodes to dictionary too.

Comment: Thanks, nice to know i can help out. I've got over 17 years experiences in software development but only create the account on stackoverflow recently.

Comment: WAW !! Can you tell me if It is possible to read this xml file as a string instead?

Comment: XElement.Parse accept a string while XElement.Load accept a file or stream.

Comment: If you look at my xml it has double quotes what happens to those? say if i paste that into @"""" it will throw an error.